# Import and use a npm package in VueJs Project

Tags: vue.js, taffydb

I have an existing project and I want to recode it with VueJs. I need to import a npm package called TaffyDB. I figured out that I have to import it in the main.js. I have to admit that I don't have any idea how to do that or how the syntax is exactly.

```
import WHAT from "WHERE";
```

taffydb is installed and I find the folder "taffydb" within my node_modules folder. In that folder is the taffy.js file.

What I don't know is how to find the details for "WHERE" and "WHAT".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $ npm install --production taffy

# and then in your code
import TAFFY from  'taffy';

Answer (score 0):

Do a npm install first on taffy `npm install --production taffy` then after that go to the code you want to use it on and require it `TAFFY = require( 'taffy' ).taffy;` in the documentation it says require it try it that way instead of doing import from.

Check the documents to https://www.npmjs.com/package/taffydb#use-it-in-nodejs

and
http://taffydb.com/

I hope this helps you out !

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I will resolve doing this:

1. Download taffy-min.js on official page
2. Move this file to /plugin folder on your project
3. In the file .vue that you need use. Copy this line on script section

   import { taffy } from '@/plugins/taffy-min.js';
4. And on mounted()methods you can write:

   const friends = taffy([                                 {"id":1,"gender":"M","first":"John","last":"Smith","city":"Seattle, WA","status":"Active"},                     {"id":2,"gender":"F","first":"Kelly","last":"Ruth","city":"Dallas, TX","status":"Active"},
   {"id":3,"gender":"M","first":"Jeff","last":"Stevenson","city":"Washington, D.C.","status":"Active"},
   {"id":4,"gender":"F","first":"Jennifer","last":"Gill","city":"Seattle, WA","status":"Active"}
   ]);

More: if you are using Typerscript, dont forget write "declare module '@/plugins/taffy-min.js';" on "delcarations.d.ts" on src folder to work.

I hope work for you! Sorry for my english! :)